# Git not responding

Tags: git

Why can't I push to remote?

```
> git status
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
 (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean


> git push

> git push --verbose
```

I didn't forget the output, It just isn't there. This never happened to me.

In my little experience, 95% of the times the problem with git has to do with credentials.
So I tried forcing git to ask me for them:

```
> git push -v --verbose
```

nothing.

I was pushing happily this morning, didn't touch anything in between...

**EDIT** (answering questions/adding info):

```
> git remote -v

origin  https://myusername-admin@bitbucket.org/myusername/someproject.git (fetch)
origin  https://myusername-admin@bitbucket.org/myusername/someproject.git (push)
```

```
> git --version

git version 2.37.3.windows.1

> Get-ComputerInfo | select WindowsProductName, WindowsVersion, OsHardwareAbstractionLayer

WindowsProductName WindowsVersion OsHardwareAbstractionLayer
------------------ -------------- --------------------------
Windows 10 Home    2009           10.0.19041.1806
```

I have neither of those env var:

```
> gci env:* | sort-object name | grep GIT_DIR
> gci env:* | sort-object name | grep GIT_WORK_TREE
```

I only have `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` in the **Path** env var.

And the behaviour I get when trying with Sourcetree is the same.

This also shows nothing:

```
> git config --global credential.helper
```

although I do have saved bitbucket credentials in my windows credential manager and I've always used those for authentication.

I'm now having the same problem with other repositories hosted on github.

At least now I'm getting a popup error:

[image]

**EDIT (Solved):**

I solved by uninstalling and reinstalling git.

Comment: Can you *reach* the remote? In other words, perhaps there's simply a network link down between you and them, whoever they are.

Comment: I have edited the answer to suggest a test using SSH instead of HTTPS, in case it helps.

Comment: I have edited the question to allow you to check what credentials are stored for bitbucket.

Comment: It is `git config --global credential.helper`, with a "a" in `credential`, not `credentil`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to check what version of Git you are using, with which OS and what [environment variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) are set (a [`GIT_DIR` or `GIT_WORK_TREE`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) for instance could influence a command like `git pull`)

But try also the same operation from a different tool (like a Visual Studio Code for instance, or an Eclipse, the later one using its own Java-based Git, called JGit). That way, you would know if the behavior is consistent or not.

---

If HTTPS is not working, try and switch to an SSH URL:

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:myusername/someproject.git
```

(make sure to [set up an SSH key in your Bitbucket account first](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/))

---

Check also what credential manager is caching your HTTPS credentials:

```
git config --global credential.helper
```

Depending on your OS and helper value, said helper might have a problem responding with the cached credentials.

On Windows, assuming a helper set to `manager-core`, check your credentials with, in a CMD (no bash needed):

```bash
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set "GH=%ProgramFiles%\Git"
set "PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%"

printf "host=bitbucket.org\nprotocol=https\nusername=myusername-admin"| git-credential-manager-core get
```

The OP confirms an issue with the `credential.helper` (empty)

**OP's solution**:  uninstalling and reinstalling git.

Comment: In the end I solved by uninstalling and reinstalling git. Thanks for the tips tough!

Comment: @IDK OK. I have included your solution in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Try
Checking if you have remote a repository

`git remote -v`

if you have then

`git push <yourbranchname>`

Or...
Change something a commit again

- Try to change a file
- `git add <file>`
- `git commit -m 'commit'`
- `git push`